# Python dictionary manipulation from dot notation

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

What I want to do is create a "dictionary pathway" from a string. I don't think that's the right term, but basically, if i have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
'myDict'{
    'classes':{
        'students':{
            'grades':{
                'grade':'A'
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

and I have a variable called `current_dict` that has `myDict` in it right now, so `current_dict = myDict`, and a string stored as `"classes.students.grades"`, I would like to manipulate that string so that I have `[classes][students][grades]`. However, I want to be able to use that to reassign `current_dict`. So, I would like to say `current_dict = myDict['classes']['students']['grades']`. I tried turning the string into `"[classes][students][grades]"`, but that doesn't work, because it identifies the whole thing as a single string, including the brackets. How can I manipulate `"classes.students.grades"` so that I can reassign `current_dict = myDict['classes']['students]['grades']`? So, after I have done this, `current_dict` would be `grades` and would look like:

```
{
    grade': 'A'
}
```

Comment: Use a `class` object or `collections.namedtuple`; at some point you might need to cheat with `collections.defaultdict`, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: It looks like you're trying to reinvent object-oriented programming, but sort of inside out. Is there any reason you don't just use objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
current_dict = myDict
mystring = "classes.students.grades"
myPath = mystring.split(".")
for part in myPath:
    current_dict = current_dict[part]
```

But I think there's probably a much easier way to do this, if you just tell us what you want this for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string1='classes.students.grades'
string2=string1.split('.')
myDict[string2[0]][string2[1]][string2[2]]['grade2']='B'
myDict
```

my output was

```
{'classes': {'students': {'grades': {'grade1': 'A', 'grade2': 'B'}}}}
```

Note that I changed grade to grade1 in my dictionary. Why not use a pandas DataFrame?